# Keep randomly getting "Server Application not Available"

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

We have a Windows Server 2003 R2 server running IIS.

Every couple of days now it seems that random sites will suddenly get `Server Application Unavailable`. Note that these (so far) have not even been ASP.NET sites, but ones written in simple HTML pages, and even ones with NO pages (strictly directory browsing).

Simply recycling the application pools makes the error go away.

The message makes reference to looking in the event logs to see what caused the error. Doing so yields no relevant entries though in ANY of the various event logs on the machine, which leaves me with nothing to start with to try to figure this out.

Many sites on line say this is a .NET issue, but again, these aren't even .NET sites. 
(In fact, I don't recall it happening to ANY of our .NET sites yet.)

Any clues or ideas about where to start looking to figure this out?

Comment: Are these sites running in the same App Pool? If so you may want to configure each one to run in its own App Pools to aid in troubleshooting and to isolate them so one site won't affect another site and to imporove the performance of each site.

Comment: I'll have to check that as time goes on...

Comment: Have you monitored your worker processes (w3wp.exe)?  If it were me, I'd be watching them via perfmon, and procmon.  Is there a pattern (regularity of failure, Etc.?).  Anything in the event logs?

Comment: Well, we've moved one site to it's own app pool. We'll see if this helps anything...

Comment: We had two sites that this was happening to regularly... As per @joeqwerty's suggestion, I separated them each into their own app pools, and they are each working fine now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these sites running in the same App Pool? If so you may want to configure each one to run in its own App Pool to aid in troubleshooting and to isolate them so one site won't affect another site and to improve the performance of each site.

Comment: Still don't know *what* / *why* happened,  but at least it's not happening anymore.